# Flyway doesn't create migrations to database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, flyway

I'm new to flyway and I'm trying to create a migration of my database. I created `V1_1__CREATE_TABLES.sql` file in `/resources/migrations`, and started the app, but it just doesn't works. I also fiend a lot of threads on this topic, but all the answers I senn was useless for me. So here you can see my code:

Here's my maven dependencies:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.diary</groupId>
    <artifactId>diary</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>diary</name>
    <description>School electronic diary</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's `application.properties` file

```java
#spring
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/diary
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=4122
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

#flyway
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:migrations
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/diary
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=4122
spring.flyway.schemas=public
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

And here's my sql file:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    login VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    patronymic VARCHAR(255),
    roleId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT userRoles FOREIGN KEY (roleId) REFERENCES roles(id)
    primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    primary key (id)
);
```

If you know what can be a problem, please, tell me, I'd really apreciate it!

Comment: try to remove the property `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:migrations` and build and start spring boot again

Comment: Well, i removed this line from ```application.properties``` and moved SQL file to ```resources/db/migration``` directory, but it still not working :(

Comment: try to rename your file from `V1_1__CREATE_TABLES.sql` into `V2_1__CREATE_TABLES.sql`

Comment: still not working

Comment: change `spring.flyway.schemas=public` into `spring.flyway.schemas=diary` This for sure should be an issue as the schema that you are connecting is this one.

Comment: well, the problem was that I added another dependency. I added flyway as plaugin to maven, but I had to add it as dependency. Now it works